# Converting large strings from BSTR tp std::string?

Tags: c++, string, typeconverter, bstr

I have string in BSTR, and I would like to convert it using W2CA (WideCharToMultiByte):

```
USES_CONVERSION;
std::string myMBS = W2CA(myBSTR); // myBSTR is BSTR
```

But when string is extremely large - it throws exception "StackOverFlowException" on this line.

But when I use this:

```
std::wstring myWide(myBSTR);
std::string myMBS(myWide.begin(), myWide.end());
```

I works fine.
Could anyone help with this behavior?

**UPDATE**: With large string I mean string about 10MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the actual definition of `W2CA` from `atlconv.h`:

```
#define W2CA(lpw) ((LPCSTR)W2A(lpw))
```

Now look at the definition of `W2A`:

```
#define W2A(lpw) (\
    ((_lpw = lpw) == NULL) ? NULL : (\
            (_convert = (lstrlenW(_lpw)+1), \
            (_convert>INT_MAX/2) ? NULL : \
            ATLW2AHELPER((LPSTR) alloca(_convert*sizeof(WCHAR)), _lpw,
                         _convert*sizeof(WCHAR), _acp))))
```

It calls [`alloca`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5.aspx), which allocates memory on the stack.  So naturally if the string is very long, you risk exhausting the available stack space.

Comment: Yep, saw it. Looks like using alloca with large string - very bad idea. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: @user2706838: Don't use `W2CA` (or at least not for strings that could be large).  Write an inline function to call `WideCharToMultiByte` for you (and more directly) and use that instead.

Comment: And with C++11, it's now possible/legal to pass the char array wrapped by `std::string` directly to  `WideCharToMultiByte`.